# How to load dll extension after SSMS 2017 finished to load

Tags: add-in, vsix, ssms-2017

How can I load `dll` every time immediately after the `SSMS 2017` finish to load itself

(I want to register to particular  `event`)

If you think I need to do it with the attribute `[ProvideAutoLoad]` please, give me the `parameters`.

thank you

Ron

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1243356/Create-Your-Own-SQL-Server-Management-Studio-SSMS) from CodeProject by *Stefan Timovski* to get your extension development ready is what I referenced and explains all of that step-by-step very well.

**Short answer:**
Use the *ProvideAutoLoad* attribute below in the *.pkgdef* file

```
    ...
    [ProvideAutoLoad(UIContextGuids80.NoSolution)]
    public sealed class YourCommandNamePackage : Package
    {
      ...
    }
```